# Solve the inequality: $|x^2 − 4| < 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This is a question on a calculus assignment our class received, I am a little confused on a few parts to the solution, can someone clear a few things up with it?

Since $x^2-4 = 0$ that means $x = 2$ and $x = -2$ are turning points.

When $x < -2$ :
$x^2-4<2$
$x^2<6$
$x < \sqrt{6}$ and $x < - \sqrt{6}$

But the solution says that $x > -\sqrt{6}$, what am I not getting?

Answer (score 3):

$$|x^2-4|<2 \\ \implies -2<x^2-4<2 \\ \implies 2<x^2<6 \\ \implies \sqrt{2}<\pm x<\sqrt{6} \\ \implies \sqrt{2}<x<\sqrt{6},\ \ -\sqrt{2}>x>-\sqrt{6}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$|x^2 - 4| < 2 \implies -2 < x^2 - 4 < 2 \implies 2 < x^2 < 6 \implies \sqrt{2} < |x| < \sqrt{6}$$

So, the solutions are $x$ such that $-\sqrt{6} < x < -\sqrt{2}$ or $\sqrt{2} < x < \sqrt{6}$. Drawing the number line is very helpful for these exercises.

Answer (score 2):

$$|x^2 - 4| < 2 \implies -2 < x^2 - 4 < 2$$

$$\implies 2 < x^2 < 6$$

$$ \implies \sqrt{2} < |x| < \sqrt{6}$$

So

$\sqrt{2} < -x < \sqrt{6} \implies -\sqrt{2} > x > -\sqrt{6}$

or
  $ \implies \sqrt{2} < x < \sqrt{6}$ and its done...

Answer (score 2):

In this case, we have $ |x^2 - 4| < 2 $, which leads to $ (x^2 - 4)^2 < 4 $, because $ |a| = \sqrt{a^2} $ where the root is the positive result.

Continuing, $ (x^2 - 4)^2 - 4 < 0$ and $ x^4 - 8x^2 + 12 < 0 $ or $ (x^2 - 6)(x^2 - 2) < 0 $.

This is only satisfied when $ x^2 > 2 $ and $ x^2 < 6 $. This is possible when $ \sqrt{2} < x < \sqrt{6} $ or $ -\sqrt{2} > x > -\sqrt{6} $.

To figure this out, break it into cases. When is $x^2 > 2$? One case is when $ x > \sqrt{2} $. Then you compare this with the two possibilities of the other inequality, namely $x < \sqrt{6}$ and $x > -\sqrt{6}$. You will notice that one result will be eliminated as impossible. Then do the two cases for when $ x < -\sqrt{2} $. Same thing will happen.